# Guest User not expanded when mail sent to Exchange DL

Tags: exchange-server

Scenario:

Exchange Online only. We have a mixture of regular users and "guest" users (Azure AD users invited to collaborate). We also have a number of plain old Distribution Lists (DLs) NOT Microsoft 365 Groups.

I have a guest user complaining that they are not receiving emails sent to a DL they are a member of. Checked and this is true. They receive direct email sent to them, but emails sent to a DL they are a member of is not going through.

Did a Message Trace on a recent email sent to that DL and discovered the guest user is not being enumerated when the DL is expanded (so no email delivery attempt is being made). I have no idea why.

Checked that email address is correct

Checked that guest user is member of DL

Checked that other email sent to guest user  is delivered fine

Also determined that the guest user is not visible in the GAL (this is apparently default behavior for guest users). I don't feel this should be a factor but adding it just in case).

I'm actually completely at a loss as to what to do next.

Comment: this question is better asked at https://serverfault.com